# access fields in a collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am using nodejs and mongodb

```
    "image" :
    "comments" : 
    "date" : 
    "name" : 
    "description" :
    "author" : {
        "id" : 
        "username" : 
    },
    "user" 
    "__v" 
}
```

these are the fields in my collection named Blog.
i want to access the username

```
Blog.find({author.username:req.params.username}
```

i tried doing it like above but am getting error.
How can i access the username from inside author

Comment: What is the error that you're getting ? Did you try this with quotations : `Blog.find({'account.username':req.params.username})` ??

Comment: sorry,i wrote account in the question by mistake.I have changed it to author now.

Comment: Do you mean it's working now ? though you made a typo you shouldn't be getting any error just `.find()` would return `[]`, what is the that you're seeing in case if it's not working..

Comment: @srinivasy it was giving error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose

```
// Blog Schema 
{
"description" : { type : string },
"author" : {
    "id" : string
    "username" : string, 
    "type": { type : string } // auther is an object with a type property
 }
}

// Blog find query 
const username = req.params.username  // user name 
Blog.find({"author.username" : username }, (err, data) => {
  if(err) {
    // error handler 
  }else{
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have made a typo. You are using `account`, but in the schema it is `author`. Try this:

```
Blog.find({author.username:req.params.username}
```

Comment: sorry,i wrote account in question by mistake.I have changed it to author now